# Fast weighted mean & variance of 10 bins

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, variance

I would like to speed up a part of my code but I don't think there is a possible better way to do the following calculation:

```
float invSum = 1.0f / float(sum);

for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
{
    histVec[i] *= invSum;
}

for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
{
    float midPoint = (float)i*binSize + binOffset;
    float f = histVec[i];
    fmean += f * midPoint;
}

for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
{
    float midPoint = (float)i*binSize + binOffset;
    float f = histVec[i];
    float diff = midPoint - fmean;
    var += f * hwk::sqr(diff);
}
```

`numBins` in the for-loops is typically 10 but this bit of code is called very often (frequency of 80 frames per seconds, called at least 8 times per frame)

I tried to use some SSE methods but it is only slightly speeding up this code.  I think I could avoid calculating twice midPoint but I am not sure how.  Is there a better way to compute fmean and var?

Here is the SSE code:

```
// make hist contain a multiple of 4 valid values
    for (int i = numBins; i < ((numBins + 3) & ~3); i++) 
        hist[i] = 0;

// find sum of bins in inHist
    __m128i iSum4 = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i += 4) 
    {
        __m128i a = *((__m128i *) &inHist[i]);
        iSum4 = _mm_add_epi32(iSum4, a);
    }

    int iSum = iSum4.m128i_i32[0] + iSum4.m128i_i32[1] + iSum4.m128i_i32[2] + iSum4.m128i_i32[3];

    //float stdevB, meanB;

    if (iSum == 0.0f)
    {
        stdev = 0.0;
        mean = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {   
        // Set histVec to normalised values in inHist
        __m128 invSum = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f / float(iSum));
        for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i += 4) 
        {
            __m128i a = *((__m128i *) &inHist[i]);
            __m128  b = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(a);
            __m128  c = _mm_mul_ps(b, invSum);
            _mm_store_ps(&histVec[i], c);
        }

        float binSize = 256.0f / (float)numBins;
        float halfBinSize = binSize * 0.5f;
        float binOffset = halfBinSize;

        __m128 binSizeMask = _mm_set1_ps(binSize);
        __m128 binOffsetMask = _mm_set1_ps(binOffset);
        __m128 fmean4 = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i += 4)
        {
            __m128i idx4 = _mm_set_epi32(i + 3, i + 2, i + 1, i);
            __m128  idx_m128 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(idx4);
            __m128  histVec4 = _mm_load_ps(&histVec[i]);
            __m128  midPoint4 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(idx_m128, binSizeMask), binOffsetMask);
            fmean4 = _mm_add_ps(fmean4, _mm_mul_ps(histVec4, midPoint4));
        }
        fmean4 = _mm_hadd_ps(fmean4, fmean4); // 01 23 01 23
        fmean4 = _mm_hadd_ps(fmean4, fmean4); // 0123 0123 0123 0123

        float fmean = fmean4.m128_f32[0]; 

        //fmean4 = _mm_set1_ps(fmean);
        __m128 var4 = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i+=4)
        {
            __m128i idx4 = _mm_set_epi32(i + 3, i + 2, i + 1, i);
            __m128  idx_m128 = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(idx4);
            __m128  histVec4 = _mm_load_ps(&histVec[i]);
            __m128  midPoint4 = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(idx_m128, binSizeMask), binOffsetMask);
            __m128  diff4 = _mm_sub_ps(midPoint4, fmean4);
            var4 = _mm_add_ps(var4, _mm_mul_ps(histVec4, _mm_mul_ps(diff4, diff4)));
        }

        var4 = _mm_hadd_ps(var4, var4); // 01 23 01 23
        var4 = _mm_hadd_ps(var4, var4); // 0123 0123 0123 0123
        float var = var4.m128_f32[0]; 

        stdev = sqrt(var);
        mean = fmean;
    }
```

I might be doing something wrong since I dont have a lot of improvement as I was expecting. 
Is there something in the SSE code that might possibly slow down the process?

(editor's note: the SSE part of this question was originally asked as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837817/foor-loop-optimisation-sse-comparison, which was closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: You could still collapse the first loop into the second, since you are not changing `histVec` afterwards, no? Also, probably not significant, but why create a temp variable f? Just use histVec[i] (the compiler should optimize that though).

Comment: Yes that is a good point, but as you said I also think that the compiler would optimize that

Comment: What about `hwk::sqr(diff)` performance? Maybe you could use a different implementation to get some speed up?

Comment: hwk::sqr is basically a template for val * val, I could check the time of computation if i directly type diff * diff but again the compiler will probably consider hwk::sqr as val * val

Comment: The operations are pretty trivial for current desktop processors. Most promising would be any kind of parallelization. *If* the array is large, reducing the number of loops would help. --- FWIW, there's little point in using float, I'd default to `double`. -- suggestion: post the SSE code to a new question and let's work on that.

Comment: Normally you _can_ compute both mean and variance in single loop by using the fact that ∑(x - x̅)² = ∑x² - x̅², but I am not quickly sure how to adjust it for the weighted case you have.

Comment: You probably want to use an online version of your algorithm, to eliminate the need for two passes.  I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Weighted_incremental_algorithm) is what @JanHudec is referring to.

Comment: @Jason, yes, that is. I only remembered the basic variant off the top of my head.

Comment: Does your platform have a floating point processor or native floating point instructions?  If your code is calling a software library for floating point, you could improve performance by using Fixed Point arithmetic.  Search the internet for "c++ fixed point arithmetic".

Comment: What does your profiler say?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: He's on x86 with SSE.  He has very good hardware floating point.  BTW, I updated my answer with more suggestions for optimizing the common 10-bin case.

Comment: "I don't think there is a possible better way": there are many possible simplifications, leading to a probable threefold or fourfold improvement.

Comment: If there are just 10 bins, is it really worth to optimize that part of the code ? It will cost like 100 floating operations, to be compared to the computation of the image histogram, probably over 100000 integer operations.

Answer (score 5):

I only just realized that your data array starts out as an array of int, since you didn't have declarations in your code.  I can see in the SSE version that you start with integers, and only store a float version of it later.

Keeping everything integer will let us do the loop-counter-vector with a simple `ivec = _mm_add_epi32(ivec, _mm_set1_epi32(4));`  Aki Suihkonen's answer has some transformations that should let it optimize a lot better.  Especially, the auto-vectorizer should be able to do more even without `-ffast-math`.  In fact, it does quite well.  You could do better with intrinsics, esp. saving some vector 32bit multiplies and shortening the dependency chain.

---

**My old answer, based on just trying to optimize your code as written, assuming FP input**:

You may be able to combine all 3 loops into one, using [the algorithm @Jason linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Weighted_incremental_algorithm).  It might not be profitable, though, since it involves a division.  For small numbers of bins, probably just loop multiple times.

Start by reading the guides at http://agner.org/optimize/.  A couple of the techniques in his Optimising Assembly guide will speed up your SSE attempt (which I edited into this question for you).

- combine your loops where possible, so you do more with the data for each time it's loaded / stored.
- multiple accumulators to hide the latency of loop-carried dependency chains.  (Even FP add takes 3 cycles on recent Intel CPUs.)  This won't apply for really short arrays like your case.
- instead of int->float conversion on every iteration, use a float loop counter as well as the int loop counter.  (add a vector of `_mm_set1_ps(4.0f)` every iteration.)  `_mm_set...` with variable args is something to avoid in loops, when possible.  It takes several instructions (esp. when each arg to `setr` has to be calculated separately.)

gcc `-O3` manages to auto-vectorize the first loop, but not the others.  With `-O3 -ffast-math`, it auto-vectorizes more.  `-ffast-math` allows it to do FP operations in a different order than the code specifies.  e.g. adding up the array in 4 elements of a vector, and only combining the 4 accumulators at the end.

Telling gcc that the input pointer is aligned by 16 lets gcc auto-vectorize with a lot less overhead (no scalar loops for unaligned portions).

```
// return mean
float fpstats(float histVec[], float sum, float binSize, float binOffset, long numBins, float *variance_p)
{
    numBins += 3;
    numBins &= ~3;  // round up to multiple of 4.  This is just a quick hack to make the code fast and simple.
    histVec = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(histVec, 16);

    float invSum = 1.0f / float(sum);
    float var = 0, fmean = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
    {
        histVec[i] *= invSum;
        float midPoint = (float)i*binSize + binOffset;
        float f = histVec[i];
        fmean += f * midPoint;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
    {
        float midPoint = (float)i*binSize + binOffset;
        float f = histVec[i];
        float diff = midPoint - fmean;
//        var += f * hwk::sqr(diff);
        var += f * (diff * diff);
    }
    *variance_p = var;
    return fmean;
}
```

gcc generates some weird code for the 2nd loop.

```
        # broadcasting fmean after the 1st loop
        subss   %xmm0, %xmm2    # fmean, D.2466
        shufps  $0, %xmm2, %xmm2        # vect_cst_.16
.L5: ## top of 2nd loop 
        movdqa  %xmm3, %xmm5    # vect_vec_iv_.8, vect_vec_iv_.8
        cvtdq2ps        %xmm3, %xmm3    # vect_vec_iv_.8, vect__32.9
        movq    %rcx, %rsi      # D.2465, D.2467
        addq    $1, %rcx        #, D.2465
        mulps   %xmm1, %xmm3    # vect_cst_.11, vect__33.10
        salq    $4, %rsi        #, D.2467
        paddd   %xmm7, %xmm5    # vect_cst_.7, vect_vec_iv_.8
        addps   %xmm2, %xmm3    # vect_cst_.16, vect_diff_39.15
        mulps   %xmm3, %xmm3    # vect_diff_39.15, vect_powmult_53.17
        mulps   (%rdi,%rsi), %xmm3      # MEM[base: histVec_10, index: _107, offset: 0B], vect__41.18
        addps   %xmm3, %xmm4    # vect__41.18, vect_var_42.19
        cmpq    %rcx, %rax      # D.2465, bnd.26
        ja      .L8     #,   ### <--- This is insane.
        haddps  %xmm4, %xmm4    # vect_var_42.19, tmp160
        haddps  %xmm4, %xmm4    # tmp160, vect_var_42.21
.L2:
        movss   %xmm4, (%rdx)   # var, *variance_p_44(D)
        ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L8:
        movdqa  %xmm5, %xmm3    # vect_vec_iv_.8, vect_vec_iv_.8
        jmp     .L5     #
```

So instead of just jumping back to the top every iteration, gcc decides to jump ahead to copy a register, and then unconditionally `jmp` back to the top of the loop.  The uop loop buffer may remove the front-end overhead of this sillyness, but gcc should have structured the loop so it didn't copy xmm5->xmm3 and then xmm3->xmm5 every iteration, because that's silly.  It should have the conditional jump just go to the top of the loop.

Also note the technique gcc used to get a float version of the loop counter: start with an integer vector of `1 2 3 4`, and add `set1_epi32(4)`.  Use that as an input for packed int->float `cvtdq2ps`.   On Intel HW, that instruction runs on the FP-add port, and has 3 cycle latency, same as packed FP add.  gcc prob. would have done better to just add a vector of `set1_ps(4.0)`, even though this creates a 3-cycle loop-carried dependency chain, instead of 1 cycle vector int add, with a 3 cycle convert forking off on every iteration.

### small iteration count

You say this will often be used on exactly 10 bins?  A specialized version for just 10 bins could give a big speedup, by avoiding all the loop overhead and keeping everything in registers.

With that small a problem size, you can have the FP weights just sitting there in memory, instead of re-computing them with integer->float conversion every time.

Also, 10 bins is going to mean a lot of horizontal operations relative to the amount of vertical operations, since you only have 2 and a half vectors worth of data.

If exactly 10 is really common, specialize a version for that.  If under-16 is common, specialize a version for that.  (They can and should share the `const float weights[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, ...};` array.)

You probably will want to use intrinsics for the specialized small-problem versions, rather than auto-vectorization.

Having zero-padding after the end of the useful data in your array might still be a good idea in your specialized version(s).  However, you can load the last 2 floats and clear the upper 64b of a vector register with a `movq` instruction.  (`__m128i _mm_cvtsi64_si128 (__int64 a)`).  Cast this to `__m128` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

As peterchen mentioned, these operations are very trivial for current desktop processors. The function is linear, i.e. O(n). What's the typical size of `numBins`? If it's rather large (say, over 1000000), parallelization will help. This could be simple using a library like OpenMP. If `numBins` starts approaching `MAXINT`, you may consider GPGPU as an option (CUDA/OpenCL).

All that considered, you should try profiling your application. Chances are good that, if there is a performance constraint, it's not in this method. Michael Abrash's definition of "high-performance code" has helped me greatly in determining if/when to optimize:

> Before we can create high-performance code, we must understand what high performance is. The objective (not always attained) in creating high-performance software is to make the software able to carry out its appointed tasks so rapidly that it responds instantaneously, as far as the user is concerned. In other words, high-performance code should ideally run so fast that any further improvement in the code would be pointless. Notice that the above definition most emphatically does not say anything about making the software as fast as possible.

Reference:
[The Graphics Programming Black Book](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/graphics-programming-black-book/184404919)

Comment: "If it's rather large (say, over 1000000), parallelization will help": SIMD parallelization with SSE will give a immediate return, even for n=10, possibly better than whatever you can achieve with a quad- or octocore.

Comment: I agree; I wasn't really considering SIMD as parallelization. I should have mentioned it in my answer, since the SIMD instructions greatly improve performance without the overhead of spinning up multiple threads. I guess the point I was really trying to drive home is "you should try profiling your application."

Answer (score 2):

The overall function to be calculated is

```
std = sqrt(SUM_i { hist[i]/sum * (midpoint_i - mean_midpoint)^2 })
```

Using the identity

```
Var (aX + b) = Var (X) * a^2
```

one can reduce the complexity of the overall operation considerably

1) midpoint of a bin doesn't need offset b
2) no need to prescale by bin array elements with bin width

and

3) no need to normalize histogram entries with reciprocal of sum

The optimized calculation goes as follows

```
float calcVariance(int histBin[], float binWidth)
{
     int i;
     int sum = 0;
     int mid = 0;
     int var = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          sum += histBin[i];
          mid += i*histBin[i];
     }

     float inv_sum = 1.0f / (float)sum;
     float mid_sum = mid * inv_sum;

     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         int diff = i * sum - mid;  // because mid is prescaled by sum
         var += histBin[i] * diff * diff;
     }

     return sqrt(float(var) / (float)(sum * sum * sum)) * binWidth;
}
```

Minor changes are required if it's `float histBin[]`;

Also I second padding histBin size to a multiple of 4 for better vectorization.

**EDIT**

Another way to calculate this with floats in the inner loop:

```
 float inv_sum = 1.0f / (float)sum;
 float mid_sum = mid * inv_sum;
 float var = 0.0f;

 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      float diff = (float)i - mid_sum;
      var += (float)histBin[i] * diff * diff;
 }
 return sqrt(var * inv_sum) * binWidth;
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `var2` as the accumulator in your loop.

Comment: I meant to use `var`; anyway, arithmetic is now fixed. One shouldn't try to get rid of `fmean` calculation -- if done while updating the histogram, the cost is higher (assuming the histogram is updated much more frequently than 10 times). Same goes even for sum accumulating (assuming it's increased one per entry -- we haven't actually seen the definition or source code for that)

Comment: @trexgris should see some nice improvement in how well this vectorizes.  I hadn't realized the data started out as integer!  That makes adding the loop counter a ton easier.  For your first version, start with `setr_epi32(0-mid, 1-mid, 2-mid, 3-mid)`, and add `set1_epi32(sum)` every time.  Hopefully the auto-vectorizer sees that, and can vectorize without `-ffast-math` since it's all integers.

Comment: `gcc -O3 -msse4.2 -mtune=sandybridge` does great stuff with your version.  It unrolls the first loop completely, and optimizes away all the multiplies.  (using `leal  (%r9,%r9,2), %ecx` to multiply by 3, for example.)  It vectorizes the 2nd loop, using slow-ish-on-haswell-and-later 6x`pmulld` and vector add/subtract.  I think it could have done a better job, and IDK why there are so many conditional branches, `pmulld`s, and `imul`s.  Still should be pretty speedy.  It doesn't spot the trick I mentioned in my last comment, of adding `set1_epi32(sum)` to get `i*sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the scaling on the global results only and keep integers as long as possible.

Group all computation in a single loop, using `Σ(X-m)²/N = ΣX²/N - m²`.

```
// Accumulate the histogram
int mean= 0, var= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numBins; ++i)
{
    mean+= i * histVec[i];
    var+= i * i * histVec[i];
}

// Compute the reduced mean and variance
float fmean= (float(mean) / sum);
float fvar= float(var) / sum - fmean * fmean;

// Rescale
fmean= fmean * binSize + binOffset;
fvar= fvar * binSize * binSize;
```

The required integer type will depend on the maximum value in the bins. The SSE optimization of the loop can exploit the `_mm_madd_epi16` instruction.

If the number of bins is a small as 10, consider fully unrolling the loop. Precompute the `i` and `i²` vectors in a table.

In the lucky case that the data fits in 16 bits and the sums in 32 bits, the accumulation is done with something like

```
    static short I[16]= { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    static short I2[16]= { 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    // First group
    __m128i i= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&I[0]);
    __m128i i2= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&I2[0]);
    __m128i h= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&inHist[0]);

    __m128i mean= _mm_madd_epi16(i, h);
    __m128i var= _mm_madd_epi16(i2, h);

    // Second group
    i= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&I[8]);
    i2= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&I2[8]);
    h= _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&inHist[8]);

    mean= _mm_add_epi32(mean, _mm_madd_epi16(i, h));
    var= _mm_add_epi32(var, _mm_madd_epi16(i2, h));
```

CAUTION: unchecked

Comment: +1 I think OP needs to calculate standard deviation (instead of variance), but this is definitely the best approach so far.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Thanks. The SSE code will be a little more complex if 32 bits arithmetic is required, but the basic principles remain. [Need to add the final horizontal accumulation as well.]